# How to fetch username and matched id as Session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to fetch different stats from whatever user is logged in. Then echo these stats out. currently when logging in i am setting a session with the username. Then i am trying to fetch the id from this username and check it again the table with the same ID and then fetch the rows from that table.

My guess is that since i am starting a session with only the username on login the code to fetch data wont work since the session does not provide the id row. i am unsure of how to get it to do that or if i am even right about that.

I appreciate all help, i am really stuck here.

This is my login code:

```
$query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    //USERDATA
    $dbPassword = $row['password'];

    if (password_verify($password, $dbPassword))
    {
        // echo "The details are correct.";
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $username;
    require_once('../../frontend/templates/account-actions.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Passwords do not match!";
    }
```

This is my code to fetch the stats data from the id of the username logged in:

```
$id = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id='$id'";
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($stmt,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Your approach needs to be corrected. As a rule, always have an Auto Increment id in every table. This will give you a unique value for each entry. Same is the case with your users table. Now when logging in, store the Auto Increment ID from users table of the logged in user. So SELECT * instead of SELECT password, to say the least. No in your stats table, store Auto Increment id from users table here in order to have a relation.

Comment: did you create session_start at the top of the page

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi I ofcourse have an auto increment ID in my users table, ive started to look at my SELECT and to change that as you say.. could you be more specific with how i should create this relation? Im not really understanding how the login would verify the password if i SELECT * instead of SELECT password?

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi am i right if i need to change this also ? $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); to fetch all instead since im not doing a SELECT *

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. Consider using PDO or Prepared Statements with mysqli. SELECT * is to select all fields. SELECT query will automatically select all entries matching the provided criteria. In case of further doubt, do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have converted your code to `mysqli` Prepared Statement with Procedural approach.

```
$username = "username_to_search";
$password = "password"; //Password is in plain text since password hash has been used.

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");

/* bind parameters for markers */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username); //"s" defines the type of data in the following variables, i.e. String for $username.

/* execute query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

$total_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id_fetched, $username_fetched, $password_fetched); //store every field fetched from the table in sequence. Note that I have added _fetched to make it easier to identify later.

if ($total_rows > 0) {
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        if (password_verify($password, $password_fetched)) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id_fetched;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username_fetched;

            require_once('../../frontend/templates/account-actions.php');
        }
        else {
            echo "Invalid Password!";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid Username!";
}
```

Once you have stored the SESSION variables properly, now you can easily find everything related to this. User your `$_SESSION["user_id"]` to search.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! One question would i be possible for you to update using password hash instead of SHA1?

Comment: I have modified the code with password hash. Please note that I have not tested it after the modification, but it should work.

Comment: im getting this error, mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in  line 44

Comment: Check total fields in your table. As I mentioned, they should match in the bracket. For example, you have id, username, password and status, so add them all as you are doing SELECT *. Or else, SELECT id, username, password FROM...

Comment: Ok i solved, i did not see that you hade entered only 3 fields from my table when i also have an email field. So i added the email field and now it works! thanks

Comment: Good to know. In case the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it as an answer to close the question properly. Happy coding!